# stmt prepare não me aparece nada

Tags: php, sql, stmt

Eu tenho este código para imprimir os dados na página que vem do banco de dados:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    include "conection.php";

    $id_login = $_SESSION["id_login"];

    $stmt =$db->prepare("select login.username, login.nome, login.id_login from login where login.id_login=?");

    $stmt->bind_param('i',$id_login);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($username,$nome,$id_login);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
?>
```

Já testei a query e está bem. Também devolve a variável de sessão `$id_login`. Mas a página fica em branco e não sei ver qual é o erro.
Obrigada.

Comment: Coloque isso no inicio da página, `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` página em branco já é um erro.

Comment: Sem nenhum `echo`, `print`, `var_dump` ou `printf` a página vai ficar em branco mesmo

Answer (score 0):

O código não parece errado, mas não há nada que faça imprimir resultado nele. Tente assim:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();

$db= new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Error: ".mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}


if ($stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT login.username, login.nome, login.id_login FROM login WHERE login.id_login = ?")) {

    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id_login);
    $id_login = $_SESSION["id_login"];

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($username, $nome, $id_login); // deve ter o mesmo número de variáveis e colunas na tabela

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $username."|".$nome."|".$id_login."<br/>";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}

$db->close();

?>
```